# using a String from firebase database outside of its class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a firebase database and im storing a number As an index of items. I access this using my database class

```
public class IndexCount {
    private String Streaming;
    public IndexCount(String Streaming){
    this.Streaming = Streaming;
}

public void databaseIndexCounter( ){

    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbref = db.getReference().child("Apps").child("IndexCount");
    dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Integer Stream = dataSnapshot.child("Streaming").getValue(Integer.class);
            Streaming = Stream.toString();
            Log.i("streamcount: ",Streaming);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access the Streaming string outside of this class and use it in my main activity to fill a textview. how can i achive this?
I thought calling this from my main activity would do the trick

```
String streamcounter = new String();
IndexCount indexcount = new IndexCount(streamcounter);
tvstreaming = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.streamcount);

indexcount.databaseIndexCounter();
Log.i("stream count: ",streamcounter);
tvstreaming.setText(streamcounter);
```

but the log does not fire so i assume my code is wrong lol. thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onDataChange will be executed in another thread ( not the main thread ) , so you need to wait until it finish its work , then do what you want.

```
public class IndexCount {
    private String Streaming;
    public IndexCount(String Streaming){
    this.Streaming = Streaming;
}

public void databaseIndexCounter( ){

    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbref = db.getReference().child("Apps").child("IndexCount");
    dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Integer Stream = dataSnapshot.child("Streaming").getValue(Integer.class);
            Streaming = Stream.toString();
            Log.i("streamcount: ",Streaming);
            // call it here 
            nextStep();
        }
    }
}
public void nextStep(){
Log.i("stream count: ",streamcounter);
tvstreaming.setText(streamcounter);
}
```

and from your main activity

```
String streamcounter = new String();
IndexCount indexcount = new IndexCount(streamcounter);
tvstreaming = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.streamcount);

indexcount.databaseIndexCounter();
```